# My chrome proxy setting change on their own

Tags: google-chrome

I am running Windows 7 and a few times a day the "Use a proxy server for your LAN (These settings will not apply to dial-up of VPN connections)." under "Local Area Network (LAN) Settings" checkbox becomes checked seemingly on it's own.  Some answers point to using Visual Studio 2010 which I am not.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you use multiple Chrome browsers and [sync their settings?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/igFh5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would check Control Panel->Internet Options->Connections->Lan Settings.  It is possible Chrome is inheriting settings from here.

Also saw this utility: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchy/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj

And it seems like you can force Chrome to use a proxy via its shortcut command: http://www.walkernews.net/2008/11/07/how-to-configure-or-disable-google-chrome-proxy-server-settings-independently/

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler does this. If you are running Fiddler, that would explain your experience.
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/proxy